# Generate/save bitmap from UIElement in metro app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, uielement

I need to save image corresponding to a `UIElement`.

I have tried following [Generate BitmapSource from UIElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831860/generate-bitmapsource-from-uielement) link for WPF but this is not working in Metro apps due to limited API.

DirectX is a way, but there is a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 3):

This is now available in Windows 8.1 see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no way other than rendering it yourself, which you can do either using `WriteableBitmap` or DirectX depending on what you want to achieve. It's all due to the missing `WriteableBitmap.Render()` method that was available in Silverlight and similar method from WPF.

*EDIT 1

Similar question also keeps being asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627830/creating-bitmap-image-from-xaml-control-using-writablebitmapex) and [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/65a6870d-1412-4701-ae12-258ed2b45452/). Hopefully an easy method to do it in WinRT/XAML is made available in the near future, but for now you have to use these workarounds.

*EDIT 2

I have just worked on it for a very short time, but I am working on implementing some basic composition code to render a visual tree to a bitmap. Got it working for some basic TextBlocks for now, but I might add other pieces soon too. You can use the code to add the elements you need in your scenario.

http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/585d3ae5a3e3#WinRTXamlToolkit.Composition%2fWriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.cs